# How can I add a border to the top of every bar in a Recharts bar chart?

Tags: javascript, recharts

I am using Recharts to create a bar chart and want to add a border to the top of every bar, similar to this example:

[image: Stacked bar chart with borders on top of each bar]

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: It would be very helpful to get a code sample of your bar chart. You can also include such a code sample in your post, so others can execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a custom shape to add a border to each bar, for example like this:

```js
const BarWithBorder = (borderHeight, borderColor) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { fill, x, y, width, height } = props;
    return (
      <g>
        <rect x={x} y={y} width={width} height={height} stroke="none" fill={fill} />
        <rect x={x} y={y} width={width} height={borderHeight} stroke="none" fill={borderColor} />
      </g>
    );
  };
};
```

This can then be used by specifiying the `shape` attribute for `<Bar />`:

```js
<BarChart width={300} height={300} data={data}>
  <Bar dataKey="a" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" shape={BarWithBorder(3, "#ff0000")} />
  <Bar dataKey="b" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" shape={BarWithBorder(3, "#00ff00")} />
</BarChart>
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-bar-chart-forked-sjcg8 for an example and https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Bar#background for the documentation of the `shape` attribute of `<Bar />`.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted (by pressing the check mark on the left). This will help the other users. Thanks!

Comment: This was very useful to get a ComposedChart with bars and a line to look good! The Line starts in the middle of the first Bar and ends in the middle of the last one. By making a custom shape for these Bar elements I was able to make the line continue. I simply had to replace the second `<rect />` with `<line x1={x} x2={x+width} y1={y} y2={y} strokeWidth={borderHeight} stroke={borderColor} />`